# Related selects in jquery where user can select up to 5 times

Tags: jquery

I have a form with 5 sets of 2 related selects.  General Academic Interest #1 which populates Major 1 etc. through 5.

```
<select name="general_1"  id="general_1">
  <option value="1">Agriculture</option>
  <option value="2">Architecture</option>
  <option value="3">Art & Design</option>
</select>

<select name="major_1" id="major_1">
  <option value=""></option>
<select>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$("#general_1").change(function() {
  var selected = $("option:selected",this).val();

  $("#majors_1").children().remove().end().append("&lt;option value=\"\"&gt;-- Select a Majors --&lt;/option&gt;");

    if(selected == "") return;

      $.getJSON( api url,{"cip_fam":selected}, function(res,code) { 
        var optionToBeAppendedTo = $("#majors_1").empty();

          $("#majors_1").attr( "size", res.length );

          for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            optionToBeAppendedTo.append($('<option/>', {value: res[i].ID, text: res[i].NAME}));
          };
      });
});
```

How can I change my javascript so on the display page I and have 5 sets - general_1 + major_1, general_2 + major_2 etc.

EDIT - updated code based on 2nd answer below:

```
$(".general").change(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      dataFilter: function(data, type){
       return type == 'json' ? data.replace(/^(\/{2})?/, '') : data;
      }
    });

    var selected = $(this).val();

    if(selected == "") return;

    var $major = $(this).next('.major').empty().append('<option value="">-- Select a Major --</option>');

    $.getJSON(compath + "/studentmajorsCFC.cfc?method=queryCipMajorRemote&returnformat=json",{"stm_cip_fam":selected}, function(res,code) { 

        $major.prop("size", res.length).empty();

            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                $major.append($('<option/>', {
                value: res[i].ID,
                text: res[i].NAME
                }));
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: are you trying to duplicate `general_1` and `major_1` select ?

Comment: @Ahtisham - general_n will be the same each time and major_n is dependent on whatever is selected in the corresponding general_n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going down the path of incremental `id` attributes here which is an anti-pattern and should be avoided.

You can simplify and DRY this code up by using common classes on all the elements, grouping the same repeated HTML structure and using DOM traversal to find related elements, something like this:

```html
<div class="course">
  <select name="general[]" class="general">
    <option value="1">Agriculture</option>
    <option value="2">Architecture</option>
    <option value="3">Art &amp; Design</option>
  </select>
  <select name="major[]" class="major">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="course">
  <select name="general[]" class="general">
    <option value="1">Agriculture</option>
    <option value="2">Architecture</option>
    <option value="3">Art &amp; Design</option>
  </select>
  <select name="major[]" class="major">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- ... further repetitions of this structure... -->
```

```js
$('.general').change(function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  if (selected == "")
    return;

  var $major = $(this).closest('.course').find('.major').empty().append('<option value="">-- Select a Majors --</option>');

  $.getJSON(apiurl, {
    "cip_fam": selected
  }, function(res, code) {
    $major.prop("size", res.length).empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      $major.append($('<option/>', {
        value: res[i].ID,
        text: res[i].NAME
      }));
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: it works fine up through this line ($major.prop("size", res.length).empty(); - i.e. if I do an alert(res.length) I get the right number.  But it's not actually filling in the results in the select with name=[major] and class="major"

Comment: no errors in console - I updated my original question to append the code that I'm actually using.  The filter just handles CFs json prefix when returning json.

Comment: One more comment - if I add this alert(res[i].NAME); in the for loop I'm getting the correct results back, so it's just not populating that 2nd select box with anything.

Comment: What do you see in the console if you put `console.log($major.length)` within the AJAX callback?

Comment: that just gives 0.  console.log(res[i].NAME) in the for loop works as expected and shows the correct results.  Likewise console.log(res.length); shows the current number of results.

Comment: Check and ensure that the HTML you're using matches that in my answer. For some reason the `next('.major')` selector in your version is not working properly, when it should be: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qwu6r81m/

Comment: Rory McCrossan - exactly the same - I agree that it's not getting that next selector.  Here's a fiddle showing my code - https://jsfiddle.net/stevelogan/to3kqdgb/6/

Comment: That's clearly not the same HTML. The `.general` and `.major` elements are not siblings. I've edited the answer to use `closest().find()` instead

Comment: Ahh - that works.  I didn't realize that the extra divs caused them not to be considered siblings.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are trying to do. You could always change the way that you are using jQuery selectors and use a shared selector like a class. See the example below. I removed you're ajax code below and replaced it with a simple test, but you can probably see how class selectors may be more dynamic for what you are trying.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".generalSelect").change(function() {
    var $generalSelect = $(this);
    var selected = $("option:selected",this).val();

    var $majorSelect = $generalSelect.closest("div").find(".majorSelect");
    $majorSelect.children().remove().end().append("&lt;option value=\"\"&gt;-- Select a Majors --&lt;/option&gt;");

      if(selected == "") {
          return;
      }
        /* 
        //Comment out ajax call since it wont work in example code. Notice the use of $majorSelect var
        
        $.getJSON( api url,{"cip_fam":selected}, function(res,code) { 
          var optionToBeAppendedTo = $majorSelect.empty();

            $majorSelect.attr( "size", res.length );

            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
              optionToBeAppendedTo.append($('<option/>', {value: res[i].ID, text: res[i].NAME}));
            };
        });*/
        
        //For showing how selectors work:
        $majorSelect.empty();
        $majorSelect.attr( "size", 3 );
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          $majorSelect.append('<option>'+"TEST"+'</option>');
        };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name="general_1"  id="general_1" class="generalSelect">
    <option value="1">Agriculture</option>
    <option value="2">Architecture</option>
    <option value="3">Art & Design</option>
  </select>

  <select name="major_1" id="major_1" class="majorSelect">
    <option value=""></option>
  <select>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div>
  <select name="general_2"  id="general_2" class="generalSelect">
    <option value="1">Agriculture</option>
    <option value="2">Architecture</option>
    <option value="3">Art & Design</option>
  </select>

  <select name="major_2" id="major_2" class="majorSelect">
    <option value=""></option>
  <select>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div>
  <select name="general_3"  id="general_3" class="generalSelect">
    <option value="1">Agriculture</option>
    <option value="2">Architecture</option>
    <option value="3">Art & Design</option>
  </select>

  <select name="major_3" id="major_3" class="majorSelect">
    <option value=""></option>
  <select>
</div>
```